# Calling scanf in argument list to printf

Tags: c, printf

When I am executing the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=10;
    printf("%d",i,scanf("%d",&i));
    return 0;
}
```

Output which I am getting is user input

while for

```
int main(void) {
    int i=10;
    printf("%d",scanf("%d",&i),i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is 1 if user input is correct(means integer type).
Why everytime scanf is executing and the output is not 10 in any of the case ?

Comment: Have you read the docs on scanf? Why would you expect this to work? Also, the evaluation order of arguments is undefined, so you cannot use an argument that depends on a different argument being evaluated before it.

Comment: Your `printf()` calls are dubious in part because the format prints a single number, in part because you're invoking undefined behaviour that depends on the order in which the arguments to the functions are evaluated, and in part because you're printing an uninitialized variable if the `scanf()` fails.

Answer (score 1):

You only display one number while you give two parameters to printf, so the second one is ignored.

In the first case you only display i, but it is modified by scanf (I believe this is actually undefined, i could be evaluated before calling scanf).

In the second case you display the number of items succesfully assigned (1).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to print the number typed by the user, call `scanf()` first, **then** call `printf()`. Don't nest one inside the other.

```
int i;
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("%d",i);
```

Comment: Thank you sir.But i want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: @DivyadeepBhalla: when you invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen and it is OK -- it is allowed because the required behaviour is undefined.  That's why it is so important to avoid undefined behaviour.  There's no good reason we can give for why.  It is simply the way your compiler does what it does.  Yes, C is great and allows you to combine operations that other languages require are separate statements, but you can't afford to abuse it (and what you're doing is abusing it).

Answer (score 1):

Number of arguments in printf is not matching

Change

```
printf("%d",scanf("%d",&i),i);
```

To

```
printf("return value of scanf: %d, i: %d",scanf("%d",&i),i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program invokes undefined behavior. `scanf()` returns number of items successfully read.
You are using only one format specifier in `printf()` for two `int` arguments.

Comment: scanf won't return the total no. of characters....what you are saying is for printf within printf.

Comment: -1: `scanf()` returns the number of items successfully matched and assigned, or `EOF`. And it is not undefined behavior to call `printf()` with excessive arguments (the opposite, that is, calling `printf()` with *too* few arguments *is* undefined behavior). If undefined behavior is to be mentioned, that should be in relation to the order of evaluation.

Comment: We've read it; what you say is incorrect for `scanf()`.  `printf()` returns the number of characters written; `scanf()` returns the number of assigning conversion specifications successfully converted (not counting `%n` conversion specifications which assign but don't convert anything).

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves; Sorry for that. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

You must match the number of printf arguments to the number of output formatters, or strange things happen.